# Modify the HTML Helpers in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, permissions, html-helper

I want to modify helpers such as this one:

```
<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Current, new { @class = "economicTextBox", propertyName = "Current", onchange = "UseCurrent();UpdateField(this);" })%>
```

to also take as a parameter another string that signifies a permission in the app, and then INSIDE the method I would determine whether or not to return the actual HTML or nothing, depending on their permission.

How would I do this?

UPDATE 2: Checkbox not rendering as readonly

When I debug and check the value of htmlHelper.CheckBoxFor(expression, mergedHtmlAttributes)._value, I get this

```
<input checked="checked" class="economicTextBox" id="Current" name="Current" onchange="UseCurrent();UpdateField(this);" propertyName="Current" readonly="true" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Current" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

but the checkbox is still rendering allowing me to change it and achieve full functionality. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a custom helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyCheckBoxFor<TModel>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression, 
    string permission, 
    object htmlAttributes
)
{
    if (permission == "foo bar")
    {
        // the user has the foo bar permission => render the checkbox
        return htmlHelper.CheckBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
    }
    // the user has no permission => render empty string
    return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}
```

and then:

```
<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(
    m => m.Current, 
    "some permission string",
    new {  
        @class = "economicTextBox", 
        propertyName = "Current", 
        onchange = "UseCurrent();UpdateField(this);" 
    }) 
%>
```

---

UPDATE:

Here's how you could modify the HTML helper so that it renders a readonly checkbox instead of an empty string if the user has no permissions:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyCheckBoxFor<TModel>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression,
    string permission,
    object htmlAttributes
)
{
    if (permission == "foo bar")
    {
        // the user has the foo bar permission => render the checkbox
        return htmlHelper.CheckBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
    }
    // the user has no permission => render a readonly checkbox
    var mergedHtmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
    mergedHtmlAttributes["readonly"] = "readonly";
    return htmlHelper.CheckBoxFor(expression, mergedHtmlAttributes);
}
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I want. But where would I place this method? In just an extra class somewhere and then reference the namespace in the aspx view?

Comment: @slandau, you should place this method in a public static class and the namespace into which this class has been declared should be included in the view so that it can resolve the extension method. You may take a look at the following tutorial as to how HTML helpers work: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: I'm getting this error on the class: Error 17 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>' does not contain a definition for 'CheckBoxFor' and no extension method 'CheckBoxFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @slandau, add `using System.Web.Mvc.Html`.

Comment: How would I, instead of returning an empty html string, return the same control, but instead greyed out and disabled?

Comment: @slandau, please see my update for how this could be achieved.

Comment: So I'm confused, what do I pass in on the front end? I updated my code above with the error I am receiving and how I have everything setup.

Comment: @slandau, you are not calling the helper correctly in your view. Instead of `Chatham.Web.Controllers.CustomHelpers.CheckBoxForWithPermission(...)` it should be `<%= Html.CheckBoxForWithPermission(...) %>`. I would recommend you reading about how [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) work in .NET.

Comment: Okay you're correct, however, how does that work? I'm just curious. -- NVM, i'll read that article

Comment: @slandau, that's how extension methods work. They allow you to add custom methods to existing classes. In this case the existing class is `HtmlHelper` and you have an instance of it in the view. So you could call your custom method on this instance as long as it is in scope (added proper usings). So even if it is a static method it is invoked on an instance. Basically it's syntactic sugar provided by the compiler.

Comment: I hate to keep bugging you, but this is all just new stuff to me. But the checkbox is not rendering as readonly. Still allows me to check/uncheck, see above, ill update now

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. I've tested my code and it worked fine for me. Also in the generated HTML I see `readonly="true"` which should be `readonly="readonly"`. Are you sure you have used the exact code I provided.

Comment: hmm, maybe its a crossbrowser thing? im testing it in firefox. does the outputted html look right?

Comment: yea i tested with readonly="readonly" first and then i thought that was the issue. testing it with both now again and neither works =/

Comment: The exact HTML that's displayed on the page in Firefox is <input type="checkbox" value="true" readonly="readonly" propertyname="Current" onchange="UseCurrent();UpdateField(this);" name="Current" id="Current" class="economicTextBox" checked="checked"> -- and it still is enabled

Comment: @slandau, try with `disabled="disabled"`.

Comment: disabled works, idk why readonly didn't. well, i guess that's all the questions i have. thank you so much for your persistance. if there's anyway i could recommend you, let me know, haha

Comment: can i bother you once more? how would the extension method look for something like this:

<%= Html.TextBox("RateTimeStamp", Model.RateTimeStamp.HasValue ? Model.RateTimeStamp.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") : "", new { @class = "economicTextBox", propertyName = "RateTimeStamp", onchange = "parseAndSetDt(this);", dataType = "Date" })%> -- its not a TextBoxFor method, so it would be a little different right?

Answer (score 2):

In order to do what you want, you need to create you own HTML Helper.  The HTML Helper methods are just extension methods.  As such you can easily create your own that does the proper permission checking and then if it passes, call the default Html.CheckBoxFor with the rest of the parameters.

This previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032806/custom-html-helpers-in-asp-net-mvc-2) has a decent example of creating custom helpers.

Comment: That...makes sense. Kind of. So for instance, I would create the method where? And how would I call it from the view? And then how would I call the HTML Helper from the method?